# Get number of requisitions made by the user in a day

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, backend

I have a POST ENDPOINT in my API where i want to register all work journals a worker made.

```
export const registerPoint = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

const user = res.locals.decoded;
const {id} = user;

const ponto = new Ponto;

ponto.datePoint = new Date();
ponto.user_id = id;

//this numPoint should restart every day for that user...
ponto.numPoint = 1; 


res.json({ msg: "Register point Route", user, id });
return;
```

}

how can i control how many times this requisition was made by a worker?
I want to control the variable numPoint, when the user makes this requisition it should increase by 01 and then in the final of the day returns it to 0.

Anyone knows about a solution or about a npm package that can handle this?

EDIT: Im storing all the data with SEQUELIZE + MYSQL.

Comment: What do you mean control? You want to limit the number of times your endpoint is hit?

Comment: How do you intend to store the data? You could consider using a database as you'll need to store the requisition data somewhere. You can't keep this in memory because when you restart your app the data will be lost.

Comment: @RinkeshP not limit, but control how many times a user named John for example has registered his point. 
Definition of point: (point for example is what time he entered to work, left for lunch, then got back to work, then a point when he is leaving the work)

Comment: @GuyHagemans actually using MYSQL with sequelize. i've editted the question and put that info. thx

Comment: @BrenoSantin ok that's a very nice start! Conceptually what you could do is first get the value for this specific customer. if it exists, add one to the number. If it doesn't exist yet, create the entry in the database with value 1. Please note you mentioned you are planning to increase by 01, but that isn't really a good number to work with. Please use integers which should be round number (i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc). Your cronjob (see my answer below) could reset all values back to 0 every night. If you share your sequalize code in the question I can review that if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a solution that it worked for what i want.

Here is the solution below:

```
export const registerPoint = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

const decodedUser = res.locals.decoded;
const user = await User.findByPk(decodedUser.id);

const TODAY_START = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const NOW = new Date();

const markedPointsOfDay = await Ponto.findAll({
    where: {
        datePoint: {
            [Op.gt]: TODAY_START,
            [Op.lt]: NOW
        },
    }
});

const markedPointsOfDayByUser = await Ponto.findAll({
    where: {
        datePoint: {
            [Op.gt]: TODAY_START,
            [Op.lt]: NOW
        },
        UserId: (user !== null) ? user.id : decodedUser.id
    }
})



if (!markedPointsOfDay || markedPointsOfDay.length === 0) {
    const ponto = new Ponto;
    ponto.datePoint = new Date();
    if (user) {
        console.log(user)
        ponto.UserId = user.id as number;
        console.log(ponto.UserId);
    }

    if (markedPointsOfDayByUser) {
        ponto.numPoint = markedPointsOfDayByUser.length + 1;
    }

    const newPoint = await ponto.save();
    res.json({ msg: "Ponto registrado com sucesso", msg2: "Caiu no IF de quando nao encontrou ponto do DIA", newPoint })
    return;

}

if (markedPointsOfDay) {

    const ponto = new Ponto;
    ponto.datePoint = new Date();

    if (user) {
        ponto.UserId = user.id as number;
    }

    if (markedPointsOfDayByUser) {
        ponto.numPoint = markedPointsOfDayByUser.length + 1;
    } 
    

    const newPoint = await ponto.save();
    res.json({ msg: "ponto registrado", markedPoint: newPoint, markedPointsOfDayByUser });
    return;


}

return;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you could use a simple database for storing the data such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3 or MySQL.

Running jobs daily you could consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron , for example having a daily job (outside of an API call function);

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('0 0 1 * *', () => {
  console.log('running every minute to 1 from 5');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need a logging/audit trail mechanism. Since you are using MySQL you can create a new table with columns like `(datetime, user_id, action)`. Every time the user does any action, it will be logged here. Then you can easily find out the count by aggregation. You won't need to reset any count for any user, if data doesn't exist for a given date then it's count will be 0.